# PHP Yahoo Messenger API - Can I get someones display image/avatar without adding to friends?

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-messenger

Because yahoo removed the "avatar.php" script for showing the user avatar/display image (http://img.msg.yahoo.com/avatar.php?yids=username) I need to make something similar. Can someone help me with guidelines? Or where to start? Or a script to show the avatar?

Comment: do you need an avatar api implemented so that you can get user avtar on your site??

Comment: That would be great, Saurabh Sinha.

Comment: yes thats exacly what I need, I am trying for almost 1 month to find a solution to this problem, no luck so far, can you help us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this link from yahoo:

> http://img.msg.yahoo.com/v1/displayImage/yahoo/username

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be Yahoo! Messenger documentation for the Messenger Display API, found here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/topleveldisplayimageapi.html

There is also a PHP SDK for interacting with the Yahoo! Messenger API. It doesn't have a function for grabbing the avatar, but you could use one of the other functions, such as fetch_contact_list() as a starting point.

https://github.com/yahoo/messenger-sdk-php

Comment: I would like a php script, tried to use the api but no luck so far.